# How to send email through local host gmail account using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to send an email in codeigniter via my Gmail account. My current code looks like this:

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

$this->email->from('myemail@gmail.com', 'Test');
$this->email->to('test@gmail.com');

$this->email->subject('CodeIgniter Rocks Socks ');
$this->email->message('Hello World');
if($this->email->send()){
    echo 'Your email was sent, fool.';
}
else{
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```

But it is showing an error like:

> Tamilselvan 1 hour ago
>   220 smtp.googlemail.com ESMTP p2sm168603006pfi.73 - gsmtp hello: 250-smtp.googlemail.com at your service, [103.66.78.244] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 Failed to authenticate password. Error: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials p2sm168603006pfi.73 - gsmtp Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

What am I doing wrong? How to fix this?

Comment: please use "edit" button instead of adding info to comments

Comment: The error reports bad credentials, are you sure the password is correct?